# How to write CPU's DMA address to FPGA (PCIe Endpoint)?

Tags: linux, driver, dma, pci-e, memory-mapping

I'm trying to add DMA to my PCIe Linux driver using streaming DMA mappings. The FPGA (endpoint) has BAR4 configured for DMA and in my setup function I do (in order):

```
pci_set_master()
pci_enable_msi()
pci_set_dma_mask()
pci_set_consistent_dma_mask()
__get_free_pages()
dma_addr = pci_map_single(..., PCI_DMA_FROMDEVICE)
```

At this point I do not know how to tell the FPGA what my DMA address, `dma_addr`, is that was returned from `pci_map_single()`. Do I write `dma_addr` to BAR4 using `pci_write_config_dword()`? There has to be some way to tell the FPGA where it needs to write when using DMA or am I completely missing something here?

Comment: We need more information about your FPGA design. For exemple with a CycloneV, to use the PCIe the component "Avalon-MM for PCIe" component must be instanciated. And in this component we have some registers to configure to add the dma address.

Comment: We are using a Cyclone V GT development board/kit with an iMX6. Both hardware and software are learning PCIe for the first time. What I'm interested in is where within BAR4 I write the DMA address the kernel gives me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read/write data in BARx of your PCIe, you have to map the BARx with function :
`void __iomem *pcim_iomap(struct pci_dev *pdev, int bar, unsigned long maxlen);`

You can do as following for exemple:

```
/* declare the bar4 buffer */
static volatile u32 __iomem * bar4;

/* map the bar4 */
bar4 = pcim_iomap(&pdev->dev, 4, BAR4_SIZE);

bar4[DMA_VECTOR_REGISTER_ADDRESS] = dma_addr;
```

See more documentation about BARx/MMIO in [kernel Documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/PCI/pci.txt#292).

The address of DMA_VECTOR_REGISTER_ADDRESS depend of your FPGA architecture. As I can see in comments, you are using a CycloneV GT. You should look at the CRA (Configuration Registers Access) registers.
On [CycloneV GX PCIe Hard ip for Avalon-MM](http://www.altera.com/literature/ug/ug_c5_pcie_avmm.pdf) (page 83),  the register address for DMA vector begin at 0x1000 (Avalon-MM-to-PCI Express Address Translation Table).

Comment: Yes, I have already done the `pci_iomap` call. What I'm interested in is the `DMA_VECTOR_REGISTER_ADDRESS` you have in your answer. Where do I find this information? Are there offsets that are universal for all DMA setups (if so then what are they) or do I need to get that info from the hardware people on the FPGA side?

Comment: Yes, this was helpful. I am now able to access and write the correct registers: control, read address, etc.